# Excel - copy text from url to cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, web, url, import

I've got an excelsheet containing url's like so:

```
|        column A        |        column B        |
---------------------------------------------------
| www.example.com/page1  |
| www.example.com/page2  |
```

I would like to copy the html content from the url provided in column A into column B. Now I've already found some documentation how to import webcontent using VB (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa203721%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

**edit**: My apologies, I already managed to achieve parts of my query using the above source. I'm now able to extract the content from the url, iterating through a list of urls:

```
Sub WebData()

Dim wSU As Worksheet
Dim wSR As Worksheet
Dim wSS As Worksheet

Dim iForRow As Integer
Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim sURL As String

Set wSU = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("URLs")
Set wSR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
Set wSS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scrape")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
iLastRow = wSU.Cells(wSU.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
For iForRow = 1 To iLastRow Step 1
sURL$ = wSU.Cells(iForRow, "a").Value
With wSS.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"URL;" & sURL, Destination:=wSS.Range("A1"))
.Name = _
"example.aspx"
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = False
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
.WebFormatting = xlNone
.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False
.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
wSR.Cells(iForRow + 1, "a").Value = wSS.Range("A3").Value + "<br>" +    wSS.Range("A5").Value

Next iForRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Process Completed"
End Sub
```

Is there any way to import the raw html of the source into excel? Now it converts the webcontent into plain text, but i would like to preserve the html markup. I already tried setting .WebFormatting and.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns to none, with no success

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.